# Find a string on a cells range

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a VBA code to find a specific string into a cells range, after find the string I need to write something into cell bellow.

Example

I've the word "Test" on raw 1, so I need to find in what cell the string are, ex F1, after that I need to auto fill the cell below, in this case F2 with word "Ok"

Thanks in advance

Carlos

Comment: What have your tried so far?  What errors/results did you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
For i = 1 To Cells(1, 1).End(xlToRight).Column
    If InStr(Cells(1, i), "Test") Then
      Cells(2, i) = "OK"
    End If
Next




End Sub
```

Comment: Hi rangan,Thanks for your prompt reply and help, the solution that you provide fullfits all my requirements.